# Unix ls -l implementation - sorting by name?

Tags: unix, sorting, directory

I'm implementing mylsl.c (which is equivalent to "ls -l") method for Unix. Everything is set pretty much, except the contents of the current directory is being shown in a random order.

So the question is how could I sort the contents by filename?

Comment: Possible duplicate of How to sort files in some directory by the names on Linux using C - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102863/how-to-sort-files-in-some-directory-by-the-names-on-linux

Comment: Looks like homework -- if so, please tag it as such.

Comment: @Tim sorry, I guess maybe it's because I'm not really familiar with the system.. How should I do that? (I mean there're several options like "Was it helpful?" and etc. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to this problem is:

- Read all the directory entries (into memory)
- Sort them
- Write them out in sorted order

The OS does not provide a way to list them in sorted order for you.

Comment: @Emil: Yep. The system wants to make sure there's time for other answers to be posted, so you can accept the best one.