# sorted glob in C/linux

Tags: c, directory, glob

I need to find the latest created/modified files in a directory. Basically what `ls -t *.bla` does. In C, not PHP, so this question does not help me - 
[glob() - sort by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date)

---

This is an example of what no to do (forking a process is not cheap, it's lazy):

```
char filename[100];
FILE *f = popen("ls -1t /*.blabla");
fscanf(f, "%s", filename);
pclose(f);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the directory using `opendir()`, read the file names (`readdir()`) into an array, then do a `qsort()` on that array with its callback using `stat()` to read in creation or modification dates, which you then in turn use to tell `qsort()` how to sort. Do not forget to close the directory using `closedir()` (This could pimped to be even more effcient following the modification proposed in larsmans's comment below).

Finally after sorting is done, take the first/last array entry (depending on how you have sorted) and you are done.

If available you could also just use `scandir()` to have all this done at once (although you will not get around doing more stat() calls then necessary, as those need to be done in qsort's compare callback for this solution).

PS: Does anybody have an idea how to do this atomically?

Comment: This is expensive too due to all the `stat` calls. Better set up an array of `struct stat`/filename pairs and sort that.

Comment: You could also make it more efficient knowing that you only need the last few modified files (no need to sort the whole list).  Still, we don't even know if efficiency matters here so this is a fine.  Just tell us where qsort is defined (what header and library do we need?)

Comment: @David Grayson `qsort()` should be prototyped in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102863/how-to-sort-files-in-some-directory-by-the-names-on-linux